# How to load commands from batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, gis

I have a batch file which calls another batch file used for GIS software. I can run this and also input a command to run `python`, but how I can run more commands without having the user to input them? The following is the script which works:

```
@echo off
rem Root OSGEO4W home dir to the following directory
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"

rem List available o4w programs
rem but only if osgeo4w called without parameters
@echo on

set PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python
set PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%

@echo off
echo.
cmd /k python
@echo on
```

And I would like to run the following commands automatically:

```
import qgis.core
import qgis.gui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redirection of the python `script` text

```
(
echo import qgis.core
echo import qgis.gui
echo from PyQt4.QtCore import *
echo from PyQt4.QtGui import *
) | python
```

Or you put your python code into a second file and start that external python script from your batch file with something like.

```
python myScript.py
```