# Use batch file to insert command in a prompt opened by another batch file

Tags: batch-file, qgis

I am using the QGIS software, which includes the OSGeo4W.bat file. This file opens a prompt, rewrite the path variables and include some others, like the python2 enviroment and some sitepackages like the Qt4 installed with QGIS. When opened the .bat file, it opens:

[image: OSgeo4W.bat]

The problem is that i need to insert many commands in here so many times per day, like this one that converts a .ui file made by QtDesigner in .py:

```
pyuic4 -x C:\Users\Roberto\a.ui -o C:\Users\Roberto\a.py
```

As this is too much time consuming, i decided to write a batch file, call the OSgeo4W.bat and just add theses commands, but it doesnt work. The commands after the call are not runned. How can i run commands in a batch file inside the prompt created by another batch file? I am using Windows8.1. my batch file

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\OSGeo4W.bat"
pyuic4 -x C:\Users\Roberto\a.ui -o C:\Users\Roberto\a.py
rem more codes here

pause
```

Comment: Could you provide the commands you are trying to run from `OSgeo4W.bat` file

Comment: It's unclear as to what you are trying to do, so until you provide the information on the commands, perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28025326) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025469) would be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Start command to execute the commands, you could also use `timeout` to wait before each of the executions.

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\OSGeo4W.bat"
start pyuic4 -x C:\Users\Roberto\a.ui -o C:\Users\Roberto\a.py
start rem more codes here
//you can use timeout 5 to wait to execute next command
start rem ***
start rem *** 
pause
```